# Conditionally creating databases with bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I want to write a bash script that will create a set of mysql databases from a list of names ONLY IF a database of that name does not exist.  However, I want the script to produce a list of all the databases that were not created due to already existing.  How should I write my script to test for this?

My script outline for how I think it needs to go is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -h DATABASESERVER -u root -pPASSWORD <<EOF

input = $1
while IFS= read line
do
#test to see if database exists

#if exists
echo "$line" >> "$1_failures.txt"
#if does not exist

done < "$input"
```

Comment: I know that we all like shell scripts. but I can I ask you to take a look at a tool like Ansible that already has all the logic built into it?

Comment: You are trying to pass a `bash` script (and a buggy one, at that) as input to `mysql`, which expects SQL statements as input.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not the one who gets to make the decisions about what tools the office uses; I'm basically stuck bash scripting or doing this all by hand.

Comment: Aside: do not pass the password to the process that way; it will show in the process table. I suggest using mysql_config_editor and set the relevant properties (and then properly protect access to that file). To find all existing databases, use mql `show databases;` and then process that list as needed. If you pass the result of the `show databases` to a temp file, you can grep it for a given DB name in a loop, and if it is found write it to another file you can process (e.g., email) as you see fit, otherwise create the database.